# añadir mas condicionales - reactnative

Tags: reactjs, react-native

tengo mi navigate.js en react native y funciona sin problemas con el operador ternario si la sesión es autenticada me envía a una vista y si no me envía a otra, pero ahora necesito agregar una condición mas, en si necesito modificar las condiciones donde quedarían así y no he podido agregarlas:

condicion 1 :   `status == 'authenticated' && juandc.user?.tipo_usuario != 'empresa'`

condicion 2 :    `status == 'authenticated' && juandc.user?.tipo_usuario != 'usuario'`

condicion 2 :    `status !== 'authenticated'`

mi codigo:

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'

import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { LoginScreen } from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import { RegisterScreen } from "../screens/RegisterScreen";
import { RegisterFull } from "../screens/RegisterFull";

const {user, token, checkToken, logOut} = useContext(AuthContext);
const juandc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({user}))

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export const Navigator = () => {

  const {status} = useContext(AuthContext);

  if(status === 'checking') return <LoadingScreen/>

  return (
     <Stack.Navigator
     screenOptions={{
     headerShown:false,
     cardStyle:{
       backgroundColor: 'white'
     }
     }}>

{
  (status == 'authenticated' && juandc.user?.tipo_usuario != 'empresa')
  ?(
    <>
      <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />     
    </>

  ):
  (
    <>
    <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={RegisterScreen} />
    </>
  )
}

       
        
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```